# How to parse row-polymorphic records with SimpleJSON in PureScript?

Tags: json, purescript, row-polymorphism

I wrote a utility type and function that is meant to aid in parsing certain row-polymorphic types (sepcifically, in my case, anything that extends `BaseIdRows`:

```
type IdTypePairF r = (identifier :: Foreign, identifierType :: Foreign | r)


readIdTypePair :: forall r. Record (IdTypePairF r) -> F Identifier
readIdTypePair idPairF = do
  id <- readNEStringImpl idPairF.identifier
  idType <- readNEStringImpl idPairF.identifierType
  pure $ {identifier: id, identifierType: idType}
```

When I try to use it, however, it causes the code to get this type error (in my larger code base, things were working fine before I implemented the `readIdTypePair` function):

```
  No type class instance was found for

    Prim.RowList.RowToList ( identifier :: Foreign
                           , identifierType :: Foreign
                           | t3
                           )
                           t4

  The instance head contains unknown type variables. Consider adding a type annotation.

while applying a function readJSON'
  of type ReadForeign t2 => String -> ExceptT (NonEmptyList ForeignError) Identity t2
  to argument jsStr
while checking that expression readJSON' jsStr
  has type t0 t1
in value declaration readRecordJSON

where t0 is an unknown type
      t1 is an unknown type
      t2 is an unknown type
      t3 is an unknown type
      t4 is an unknown type
```

I have a [live gist](https://try.purescript.org/?gist=50fe81c73887e2c520548c63f9466be5) that demonstrates my issue.

But, here is the complete example as it stands, for posterity:

```
module Main where

import Control.Monad.Except (except, runExcept)
import Data.Array.NonEmpty (NonEmptyArray, fromArray)
import Data.Either (Either(..))
import Data.HeytingAlgebra ((&&), (||))
import Data.Lazy (Lazy, force)
import Data.Maybe (Maybe(..))
import Data.Semigroup ((<>))
import Data.String.NonEmpty (NonEmptyString, fromString)
import Data.Traversable (traverse)
import Effect (Effect(..))
import Foreign (F, Foreign, isNull, isUndefined)
import Foreign as Foreign
import Prelude (Unit, bind, pure, ($), (>>=), unit)
import Simple.JSON as JSON

main :: Effect Unit
main = pure unit


type ResourceRows = (
  identifiers :: Array Identifier
)
type Resource = Record ResourceRows

type BaseIdRows r = (
  identifier :: NonEmptyString
, identifierType :: NonEmptyString
| r
)
type Identifier = Record (BaseIdRows())

-- Utility type for parsing
type IdTypePairF r = (identifier :: Foreign, identifierType :: Foreign | r)



readNEStringImpl :: Foreign -> F NonEmptyString
readNEStringImpl f = do
  str :: String <- JSON.readImpl f
  except $ case fromString str of
    Just nes -> Right nes
    Nothing -> Left $ pure $ Foreign.ForeignError
      "Nonempty string expected."

readIdTypePair :: forall r. Record (IdTypePairF r) -> F Identifier
readIdTypePair idPairF = do
  id <- readNEStringImpl idPairF.identifier
  idType <- readNEStringImpl idPairF.identifierType
  pure $ {identifier: id, identifierType: idType}

readRecordJSON :: String -> Either Foreign.MultipleErrors Resource
readRecordJSON jsStr = runExcept do
  recBase <- JSON.readJSON' jsStr
  --foo :: String <- recBase.identifiers -- Just comment to check inferred type
  idents :: Array Identifier <- traverse readIdTypePair recBase.identifiers
  pure $ recBase { identifiers = idents }
```

Comment: What type is `recBase` supposed to be do you think? Why?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin `recBase` should have type `Resource`. In my larger production example I verified this was the case (compilation worked) before adding in the `readIdTypePair` functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `recBase` is not necessarily of type `Resource`.

The compiler has two points of reference for determining the type of `recBase`: (1) the fact that `recBase.identifiers` is used with `readIdTypePair` and (2) the return type of `readRecordJSON`.

From the first point the compiler can conclude that:

```
recBase :: { identifiers :: Array (Record (IdTypePair r)) | p }
```

for some unknown `r` and `p`. The fact that it has (at least) a field named `identifiers` comes from the dot-syntax, and the type of that field comes from `readIdTypePair`'s parameter combined with the fact that `idents` is an `Array`. But there could be more fields besides `identifiers` (which is represented by `p`), and every element of `identifiers` is a partial record (which is represented by `r`).

From the second point the compiler can conclude that:

```
recBase :: { identifiers :: a }
```

Wait, what? Why `a` and not `Array Identifier`? Doesn't the definition of `Resource` clearly specify that `identifiers :: Array Identifier`?

Well, yes, it does, but here's the trick: the type of `recBase` doesn't have to be `Resource`. The return type of `readRecordJSON` is `Resource`, but between `recBase` and return type of `readRecordJSON` stands a record update operation `recBase { identifiers = idents }`, which *can change the type of the field*.

Yes, record updates in PureScript are plymorphic. Check this out:

```
> x = { a: 42 }
> y = x { a = "foo" }
> y
{ a: "foo" }
```

See how the type of `x.a` changed? Here `x :: { a :: Int }`, but `y :: { a :: String }`

And so it is in your code: `recBase.identifiers :: Array (IdTypePairF r)` for some unknown `r`, but `(recBase { identifiers = idents }).identifiers :: Array Identifier`

The return type of `readRecordJSON` is satisfied, but the row `r` is still unknown.

---

To fix, you have two options. Option 1 - make `readIdTypePair` take a full record, not a partial one:

```
readIdTypePair :: Record (IdTypePairF ()) -> F Identifier
```

Option 2 - specify the type of `recBase` explicitly:

```
recBase :: { identifiers :: Array (Record (IdTypePairF ())) } <- JSON.readJSON' jsStr
```

---

Separately, I feel the need to comment on your weird way of specifying records: you first declare a row and then make a record out of it. FYI it can be done directly with curly braces, for example:

```
type Resource = {
  identifiers :: Array Identifier
}
```

In case you're doing it this way for aesthetic reasons, I have no objections. But in case you didn't know - now you know :-)

Comment: The separate option would be more appealing to me, `recBase :: Resource <- JSON.readJSON' jsStr`, but I think this also creates a separate type error in the live demo (please correct me if I missed something).

Comment: I think a 3rd option, if there is a way to do it in PureScript would be Type Applications (maybe by changing `readIdTypePair` to use `SProxy`); this would still allow readIdTypePair to be polymorphic, I think.

Comment: Regarding your suggestion about using Record syntax directly, I think there's a method to my madness. I discovered that when you need to re-use row types, you can't seem to get the underlying row type back from the Record type, so I use those row types with the purescript-option library, for example, so I can have Options and Records of the same underlying row types. This may fall under the category of non-obvious sensible defaults, and reminds me a lot of giving data types an extra type constructor that wraps each constructor (forgot what this trick is called in e.g. Haskell).

Comment: (this is what I was referring to with data types: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BHjIl81HgfE)

Comment: You're right, Option 2 had a mistake: I've been saying myself that the type of `recBase` is not `Resource`, and then went right ahead and declared it as such ‍♀️. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Another possibility, which I'm not sure is better than Option 2, is to use `RProxy`: `readIdTypePair :: forall r. RProxy r -> Record (IdTypePairF r) -> F Identifier` then
`idents <- traverse (readIdTypePair (RProxy :: RProxy ())) recBase.identifiers`